# I have created an application using QT.Can I update my executable using patch file

Tags: qt, desktop-application, desktop

I have created my desktop Application using QT.
I want to update my exe file by sending the patch file.
Can i do this using QT

Comment: how is the patch file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be considerably easier and less error-prone to update the *whole* exe?

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a update.exe to do that job,It will contact the server（//localhost:getversion?proname=myapp）,the web side will return the version of the software,and compare the version in local side,at last recover local exe or do nothing.There is a simple way,put your exe to the ftpserver(Use https://filezilla-project.org/),write your latest version number in a txt,download txt to compare with local exe version.
  There is only one problem, the update program can not be update itself.

Comment: Thank's Aliceljm . I want don't want the whole exe to be downloaded again.I just want to get the changed portion of exe and update the exe.Is this possible?

Comment: @PKN,I do not think it easy,if you add a new  line code in your program like "int a=4;" do you know what difference between original code,may be it change everywhere. But,when we download torrent file,we check file's hash code to make sure the file without any change(piece by piece).You can try this way.